# Go: import package from the same module in the same local directory

Tags: go

I want to create new package `mycompany` that will be published on Github at `github.com/mycompany/mycompany-go` (something similar to [stripe-go](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-go) or [chargebee-go](https://github.com/chargebee/chargebee-go) for example).

So I have created a folder `~/Desktop/mycompany-go` on my MacOS. Then inside that folder I run `go mod init github.com/mycompany/mycompany-go`.

I have only these files in that local folder:

```
// go.mod
module github.com/mycompany/mycompany-go

go 1.19
```

```
// something.go
package mycompany

type Something struct {
  Title string
}
```

```
// main.go
package main

import (
  "github.com/mycompany/mycompany-go/mycompany"
)

func main() {
  s := mycompany.Something {
    Title: "Example",
  }
}
```

However I get this error:

```
$ go run main.go 
main.go:4:3: no required module provides package github.com/mycompany/mycompany-go/mycompany; to add it:
    go get github.com/mycompany/mycompany-go/mycompany
```

I think that this is a wrong suggestion, because I need to use the local version, in the local folder, not `get` a remote version.

Basically I need to import a local package, from the same folder, from the same module.

What should I do? What's wrong with the above code?

Comment: *"I have only these files in that local folder"* -- Note that you can have ONLY ONE package per directory. File with `package mycompany` should not be in the same folder as the file with `package main`. Put files that belong to different packages (i.e. have a different name in the `package <name>` clause) into their own directories, subdirectories, etc.

Comment: See also the official [How to Write Go Code#Importing packages from your module](https://go.dev/doc/code#ImportingLocal)

Comment: E.g. `mkdir ~/Desktop/mycompany-go/mycompany`; `mv ~/Desktop/mycompany-go/something.go ~/Desktop/mycompany-go/mycompany/something.go`.

Answer (score 3):

You can't mix multiple packages in the same folder.

If you create a folder `mycompany` and put `something.go` inside it, that should fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

The Go tool assumes one package per directory. Declare the package as main in something.go.

-- main.go --

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    s := Something{
        Title: "Example",
    }
    fmt.Println(s)
}
```

-- go.mod --

```
module github.com/mycompany/mycompany-go

go 1.19
```

-- something.go --

```
package main

type Something struct {
    Title string
}
```

Runnable example: https://go.dev/play/p/kGBd5etzemK